# how the device back button lead to the previous activity?

Tags: android

friends,

i have three activities

A,B,C

A is home screen.

Activities are launched as follow A->B->C

in activity B i am writing the following code.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phone_number);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
        startActivity(i);
```

for that it goes to the dail pad and then when pressing device back button it goes to A.my requirement is go to the B.

please help me .
    Thanks in advance.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phone_number);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: You should check the below link there is example is activity life cycle you download and check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: that is weird. looks like you should come back to activity B. can you provide some more code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use startActivityforResult().

When starting the activity use.
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phone_number);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

Method

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

will be called when activity will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can override onBackPressed method to control the behaviour of Back button:

```
         @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
         // code to go to Activity B.
    }
```